# Soma iterativa bigdecimal

Tags: java

Tenho um `ArrayList` cujo um dos campos é um `BigDecimal`. Não estou conseguindo fazer essa soma de forma iterativa com laço. Alguém pode dar uma dica de como realizar essa operação?
Se fosse um `double` comum, faria da forma abaixo, mas usando o bigdecimal, não consigo pensar em uma solução:

```
for(..){
    valorTotal += lista.get(i).getValorItem(); 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adriano, no `BigDecimal` é impossível usar o operador `+`. Use `add()`:

```
valorTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;

for (...) {
    valorTotal = valorTotal.add(lista.get(i).getValorItem());
}
```

Se estiver no Java 8, dá pra usar `stream` (bem legal):

```
valorTotal = lista.stream()
    .map(NomeDaSuaClasse::getValorItem)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```